# TypeError: must be str, not tuple

Tags: python

"TypeError: must be str, not tuple" for the following code:

```
receipt.write(output_to_receipt)
```

Please may someone explain what this error is?

Comment: For which line does it print the error?

Comment: Line 27 : receipt.write(output_to_receipt)

Comment: well it IS a tuple. Need to convert it to string first

Comment: Pasting the error message into a Google search yields lots of useful results.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I had tried that but I do not quite understand what they had written as their examples were different to mine. Additionally as I am a beginner to coding I won't understand everything :)

Answer (score 9):

Change `receipt.write(output_to_receipt)` to  `receipt.write(str(output_to_receipt))`.

This will change `output_to_receipt` which is a tuple to a string and you'll be able to write.

Answer (score 3):

output_to_receipt is a tuple, so you need to convert it to a string with `str(output_to_receipt)` or `"".join(output_to_receipt)` for example.